# row is not expanding as its parent container in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, containers, row, width

Here is my code
[Screen shot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KEam.png)

current output

[current output screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJkHj.png)

i want both my icons to spaced between.

Comment: you can either use the layout builder to get the max width of the parent.

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Comment: instead of Padding, wrap the scaffold body by Container with width of double.maxFinite.

Comment: if the ans helps 2 u accpt ans and giv upv2 bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `width` to `Container()`

```
 Container(
             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
       ),
```